# Java code to remove more than one duplicate element of array

Tags: java, arrays, optimization, duplicates

There is mistake in my java code.  And, can someone please correct this or suggest some better option for the code.
I am trying to do this following procedure, and it is working for an array index`{1,n}` but I have to convert it into `{0 to n-1}` in `Java`.

`the sequence removes more than one duplicate element of array using this java code.`

`Java code`: I tried the above sequence by using the below code, please help if it is wrong somewhere.  `Java code` is working for an array index `{o to n-1}` and the above sequence is for `{1 to n}`.

```
    int[] arr = {3,6,6,5,4,3,4}                //Array which contains duplicate element  for 4 element arr can be { 1, 2, 2, 0}
    int[] A = { 99, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99,99 };
    int[] result ={ 99, 99, 99, 99,99,99,99 };
    int[] r =  { 99, 99, 99, 99,99,99,99 };
    int counter = 0, count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        boolean isDistinct = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {      
            if (arr[i] == arr[j]) {
                isDistinct = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isDistinct) {
            result[counter++] = arr[i];
               r[arr[i]]=arr[i];       //result in [0, 1, 2, 99] it will find which index have duplicate element
        }
    }

for (int i = 0; i < counter; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {     // counting the multiple occurrence of array element
        if (result[i] == arr[j]) {
            count++;
        }
      r[result[i]]=count;  // it will result in 1 = 1, 2 = 2,0 = 1 shows which index have how many multiple occurance 
    }
}                           
      // here r will result in{1, 1, 2, 99} and it is the A array of the above example

       int[]b=new int[7];
       int q=0;
       int B[]={99, 99, 99, 99, 99,99,99 };
       for (int i1 = 0; i1 <7; i1++){     // generating b array according to index 
       b[i1]=i1;
       } 
       HashSet<Integer> setOfSecondArr = new HashSet<Integer>();
       for (int i2 : result) {
           setOfSecondArr.add(i2);
        }
       for (int i3 : b) {                     //B array constructed here as in matlab code
            if (setOfSecondArr.add(i3)) {
                B[i3]=i3;
            }
       }
       // B will result [99, 99, 99, 3] means where no single occurance found B is same as B of the above example

for (int i11 = 0; i11 <r.length; i11++)
        {
             if(r[i11]!=99)
                { 
                 r[i11] = arr[i11];        // generating an array that replace r element by arr       
                }
        }
         // this loop will result in [1, 2, 2, 99]
```

Up to now the Java code is working fine, but while constructing the `C Array`, I found the problem: if I made changes to `arr = {1, 2, 2, 0}`, then all the above Java code will generate `{1,2,2,99}`, and this next for loop will generate {1,1,2,99}.  But, the result should be `{0,1,2,99}` so that no duplicate is found.

```
     for (int i1 = 0; i1 <r.length; i1++){
     boolean isDistinct = false;
     for (int i11 = 0; i11 <i1; i11++){
     if(r[i1]==r[i11] && r[i1]!=99 && r[i11]!=99)
      { 
         isDistinct = true;
         q=i11;
         break;}
      }
          if(isDistinct)   // here is the problem when this loop generates {1,1,2,99}.  And, how can I check it for 1=1? 
           {    
            if(r[i1]!=i1 ){      //here i'm implementing C array of above example  
              r[i1]=i1;          //it will use`{1,2,2,99}` and 2=2 found it will replace the element according to their index
             }
            else 
             {
             r[q]=q;

             }
           }
     }
     for (int i1 = 0; i1 <7; i1++){     
     for (int i11 = 0; i11 <7; i11++){
     if(r[i11]==99)
      { 
        q=i11;
        break;
      }                               // B+C of above example is done here
      }
            if(B[i1]!=99)
             {                       
             r[q] = B[i1];      
             }
    }   // r lastly result in [1, 1, 2, 3] but it should be {0,1,2,3} this the D array of the above example
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard classes to do that (using your first array as an example):

```
    List<Integer> ints = Arrays
            .asList(3, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4) //list from array, firt example
            .stream()
            .distinct() //filter out duplicates
            .sorted() // sort
            .map(val -> val - 1) //Minus one
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(ints);
```

The above outputs `[2, 3, 4, 5]`

The code is simply using the collection and stream API to calculate the distinct set, sort elements, and then subtract 1 from each then converting back to a list.

Comment: for this sequence arr= (3, 6, 6, 5, 4, 3, 4) there should be seveen element like in the last D= {1,2,6,5,7,3,4}. And using 4 element any like as {1,2,2,99} then it should answer in 4 element {0,1,2,99}   .

Comment: Can you perhaps clarify the logic or steps implemented by the code?

Comment: please check it again, explained through commented text